# No bluetooth on 15.10 (NUC w/ 7265 wifi+bt adapter)

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, 15.10, iwlwifi, intel-nuc

I'm wondering if someone could point me in the right direction to troubleshoot bluetooth on 15.10 (I actually moved to 15.10 to see if it would *help* the bluetooth situation). From the first boot, no bluetooth device is found (whereas this only broke on 15.04 after some updates). hcitool returns no devices and seeing as the below diagnostics was asked when I filled a question under launchpad, I'm adding here as well (in short the firmware doesn't seem to get loaded for the adapter but then again someone tells me that it wouldn't be the same driver/firmware for the bluetooth portion of the adapter as for the wireless so I  might be out in left field here - not sure exactly how that works).

Any insight?

```
$ lsusb; dmesg | egrep 'blue|firm'; lsb_release -a; uname -a
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp.
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 05ac:0220 Apple, Inc. Aluminum Keyboard (ANSI)
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0930:6540 Toshiba Corp. TransMemory Flash Memory
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05ac:1006 Apple, Inc. Hub in Aluminum Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 03f0:a407 Hewlett-Packard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[ 91.762395] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-15.ucode failed with error -2
[ 91.762436] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-14.ucode failed with error -2
[ 91.927806] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 25.30.13.0 op_mode iwlmvm
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 15.10
Release: 15.10
Codename: wily
Linux ubuntu 4.2.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 8 15:35:06 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Problem seems to have gone away after upgrading firmware. Will try and revert and see problem resurfaces.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a convenient way to revert bios back to prior version. Attributing this to kernel/bios mismatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bios update did the trick for me (updated directly from bios configuration screen). 15.10 with latest updates and latest bios for he NUC works fine, I have BT again!